# decorator that add variable to closure

Tags: python, closures, decorator

I want to write a decorator that inject custom local variable into function.

interface may like this.

```
def enclose(name, value):
    ...
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

expectation:

```
@enclose('param1', 1)
def f():
   param1 += 1
   print param1
f() will compile and run without error
```

output:

```
2
```

Is it possible to do this in python? why?

Comment: It possibly might be, but why would you do this? If the function is expecting the argument - as it must be, because it is using it by name - then why not specify it as an actual argument? And if not, why not use the normal `*args/**kwargs` syntax?

Comment: It's possible, but not something you want to be doing. It will be the source of all sorts of weird bugs where to try to figure out where a variable name is coming from or why it doesn't exist.

Comment: Another key thing to consider if you were doing this is: what would the output of calling `f()` a second time be -- 2 or 3? Also, since you call it param, could you do something like `f(param1=10)`?

Comment: What is the point of this? You could move the details of the decorator two lines down, by adding `param1 = 1` as a statement in your function.  That would get you the same effect, without inventing bizarre and impossible-to-implement decorators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought I'd try this out just to see how hard it would be. Pretty hard as it turns out.

First thing was how do you implement this? Is the extra `parameter` an injected local variable, an additional argument to the function or a nonlocal variable. An injected local variable will be a fresh object each time, but how to create more complicated objects... An additional argument will record mutations to the object, but assignments to the name will be forgotten between function invocations. Additionally, this will require either parsing of the source to find where to place the argument, or directly manipulating code objects. Finally, declaring the variables nonlocal will record mutations to the object and assignments to the name. Effectively a nonlocal is global, but only reachable by the decorated function. Again, using a nonlocal will requiring parsing the source and finding where to place the nonlocal declaration or direct manipulation of a code object.

In the end I decided with using a nonlocal variable and parsing the function source. Originally I was going to manipulate code objects, but it seemed too complicated.

Here is the code for the decorator:

```
import re
import types
import inspect


class DummyInject:

    def __call__(self, **kwargs):
        return lambda func: func

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self


class Inject:

    function_end = re.compile(r"\)\s*:\s*\n")
    indent = re.compile("\s+")
    decorator = re.compile("@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[.a-zA-Z0-9_]*")
    exec_source = """
def create_new_func({closure_names}):
{func_source}
{indent}return {func_name}"""
    nonlocal_declaration = "{indent}nonlocal {closure_names};"

    def __init__(self, **closure_vars):
        self.closure_vars = closure_vars

    def __call__(self, func):

        lines, line_number = inspect.getsourcelines(func)
        self.inject_nonlocal_declaration(lines)
        new_func = self.create_new_function(lines, func)
        return new_func 

    def inject_nonlocal_declaration(self, lines):
        """hides nonlocal declaration in first line of function."""
        function_body_start = self.get_function_body_start(lines)
        nonlocals = self.nonlocal_declaration.format(
            indent=self.indent.match(lines[function_body_start]).group(),
            closure_names=", ".join(self.closure_vars)
        )
        lines[function_body_start] = nonlocals + lines[function_body_start]
        return lines

    def get_function_body_start(self, lines):
        line_iter = enumerate(lines)

        found_function_header = False
        for i, line in line_iter:
            if self.function_end.search(line):
                found_function_header = True
                break
        assert found_function_header

        for i, line in line_iter:
            if not line.strip().startswith("#"):
                break

        return i

    def create_new_function(self, lines, func):
        # prepares source -- eg. making sure indenting is correct
        declaration_indent, body_indent = self.get_indent(lines)
        if not declaration_indent:
            lines = [body_indent + line for line in lines]
        exec_code = self.exec_source.format(
            closure_names=", ".join(self.closure_vars),
            func_source="".join(lines),
            indent=declaration_indent if declaration_indent else body_indent,
            func_name=func.__name__
        )

        # create new func -- mainly only want code object contained by new func
        lvars = {"closure_vars": self.closure_vars}
        gvars = self.get_decorators(exec_code, func.__globals__)
        exec(exec_code, gvars, lvars)
        new_func = eval("create_new_func(**closure_vars)", gvars, lvars)

        # add back bits that enable function to work well
        # includes original global references and 
        new_func = self.readd_old_references(new_func, func)
        return new_func

    def readd_old_references(self, new_func, old_func):
        """Adds back globals, function name and source reference."""
        func = types.FunctionType(
            code=self.add_src_ref(new_func.__code__, old_func.__code__),
            globals=old_func.__globals__,
            name=old_func.__name__,
            argdefs=old_func.__defaults__,
            closure=new_func.__closure__
        )
        func.__doc__ = old_func.__doc__
        return func

    def add_src_ref(self, new_code, old_code):
        return types.CodeType(
            new_code.co_argcount,
            new_code.co_kwonlyargcount,
            new_code.co_nlocals,
            new_code.co_stacksize,
            new_code.co_flags,
            new_code.co_code,
            new_code.co_consts,
            new_code.co_names,
            new_code.co_varnames,
            old_code.co_filename, # reuse filename
            new_code.co_name,
            old_code.co_firstlineno, # reuse line number
            new_code.co_lnotab,
            new_code.co_freevars,
            new_code.co_cellvars
        )

    def get_decorators(self, source, global_vars):
        """Creates a namespace for exec function creation in. Must remove
        any reference to Inject decorator to prevent infinite recursion."""
        namespace = {}
        for match in self.decorator.finditer(source):
            decorator = eval(match.group()[1:], global_vars)
            basename = match.group(1)
            if decorator is Inject:
                namespace[basename] = DummyInject()
            else:
                namespace[basename] = global_vars[basename]
        return namespace

    def get_indent(self, lines):
        """Takes a set of lines used to create a function and returns the 
        outer indentation that the function is declared in and the inner
        indentation of the body of the function.""" 
        body_indent = None
        function_body_start = self.get_function_body_start(lines)
        for line in lines[function_body_start:]:
            match = self.indent.match(line)
            if match:
                body_indent = match.group()
                break
        assert body_indent

        match = self.indent.match(lines[0])
        if not match:
            declaration_indent = ""
        else:
            declaration_indent = match.group()

        return declaration_indent, body_indent


if __name__ == "__main__":  

    a = 1

    @Inject(b=10)
    def f(c, d=1000):
        "f uses injected variables"
        return a + b + c + d

    @Inject(var=None)
    def g():
        """Purposefully generate exception to show stacktraces are still
        meaningful."""
        create_name_error # line number 164

    print(f(100)) # prints 1111
    assert f(100) == 1111
    assert f.__doc__ == "f uses injected variables" # show doc is retained

    try:
        g()
    except NameError:
        raise 
    else:
        assert False
    # stack trace shows NameError on line 164
```

Which outputs the following:

```
1111
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inject.py", line 171, in <module>
    g()
  File "inject.py", line 164, in g
    create_name_error # line number 164
NameError: name 'create_name_error' is not defined
```

The whole thing is hideously ugly, but it works. It's also worth noting that if `Inject` is used for method, then any injected values are shared between all instances of the class.

Comment: There's a step between parsing the source and bytecode hacking: parsing the AST. And Python has helpers for this in the stdlib, notably [`ast.NodeTransformer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer). And, in 3.x, [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) makes it relatively easy to build an import hook that applies the transformer for you automatically in any modules you import. But if you really want to play with stuff like this, consider [`PyMacro`](https://github.com/nikod/PyMacro), which has a ton of cool helpful features.

Comment: Looks awesome. I knew a proper syntax tree parser would be the better way to go. But I do this to further my own understanding of Python mainly. For instance, the code in the answer took me ages, but I've just knocked up a direct code manipulation version in 30 minutes. Not because it was any easier, but I understand a lot more about what is happening under the hood now. Are you sure about PyMacro? Looks like a key rebinding project.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I meant [MacroPy](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy), not PyMacro. MacroPy is one of the coolest things in the universe if you want to further your understanding of Python. (Especially because, if you get confused with something in the docs, Haoyi Li will often whip up a new 500-line script to explain it to you…) The only caveat is that if you want to learn to build import hooks yourself, and don't need backward compatibility, the way MacroPy does it is more complicated and clunky than the 3.4+ way. But just using it as a framework, that's not an issue.

Comment: By the way, if you didn't know about MacroPy, you might also not know about [the 300-odd forks and rewrites of bytecodehacks and bytecodeasm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=bytecode&submit=search) (which are dead projects from the 1.5 through 2.3 days), which make it easier to manipulate code objects. Also see [`cpyasm`](https://github.com/abarnert/cpyasm), which I wrote to be much easier to read and understand than `bytecodeasm` or `BytecodeAssembler` (but nowhere near as powerful or robust, so don't use it as anything but sample code).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using globals but I don't recommend this approach.

```
def enclose(name, value):
    globals()[name] = value

    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    return decorator

@enclose('param1', 1)
def f():
    global param1
    param1 += 1

    print(param1)

f()
```